# Add Default Chrome profile on web Driver Chrome Options on linux

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, bots

So I'm creating a bot with selenium on python, on this case I want to migrate my code to linux from windows; by instance I wanna use the default profile from chrome; so I do not have to set the session and other variables:

options.add_argument(
"user-data-dir=C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data")

This is working on windows, for linux I change the path to this:

options.add_argument(
'user-data-dir=~/home/myUser/.config/google-chrome/Default')

But currently it is open an empty sesion.

Answer (score 0):

the defaults on linux are stored on something like
~/.config/google-chrome/Default

try

```
options.add_argument( 'user-data-dir=~/.config/google-chrome/Default')
```

Comment: I tried that approach and doesn't work...:V